# How to restore mysql databases after upgrading to mariadb

Tags: mysql, mariadb

While installing `mariadb-server`, it moved all of my existing databases to `/var/lib/mysql-5.7` and created a new `/var/lib/mysql` folder.

How do I restore these databases from the backup folder?

Comment: Why did you not use mysqldump? I doubt what you did will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restoring a MySQL or MariaDB database will involve "`exporting`" it and then "`importing`" it. With "`phpmyadmin`" use it to export your database. Copy the resulting file to a temporary location or USB drive and use "`phpmyadmin`" to import it.

Alternatively use: [mysqldump](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/backup-and-restore-mysql-database-using-mysqldump/)

Answer (score 2):

Just have a copy of the mysql-5.7 folder (in /var/lib while maria db got installed) in some temporary location.

Now, in your /var/lib, you will have a folder called mysql which is your current db (without your old dump).

Now, stop your mysql. Move the mysql folder in /var/lib to some location for safety purpose and move the mysql-5.7 folder to /var/lib and rename it as mysql. Set the same privileges as set for previous mysql folder.

Restart mysql service again. You will have the old dump now.