# Accidentally installed MariaDB over Mysql. How do I recover my Mysql databases?

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, database, mariadb

I installed MariaDB and failed to notice it replaces Mysql. During the install, it moved the Mysql data directory to mysql-5.7. I removed MariaDB and reinstalled Mysql and tried to restore my databases by simply moving them from mysql-5.7 to mysql and restarting Mysql. Mysql won't start again and therefore I cannot use mysqldump as suggested here - [How to restore mysql databases after upgrading to mariadb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/793775/how-to-restore-mysql-databases-after-upgrading-to-mariadb). How can I restore my databases?

For reference, I am running Ubuntu Server 16.04 and Mysql 5.7.

Comment: What do you mean by it moved data directory to mysql-5.7?

Comment: While installing MariaDB, it stated `The old data directory will be saved at new location.

A file named /var/lib/mysql/debian-*.flag exists on this system. The number indicated a database binary format version that cannot automatically be upgraded (or downgraded).

Therefore the previous data directory will be renamed to /var/lib/mysql-* and a new data directory will be initialized at /var/lib/mysql.`
Since the only folders in /var/lib that match that are mysql-files and mysql-5.7 and mysql-files is empty, I assume the mysql folder was moved to mysql-5.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured this out:

1. Copy the renamed folder (/var/lib/mysql_5.7) to a safe location. (If you preserve ownership & permissions you can probably skip fixing them in step 4.)
2. Uninstall MySQL and remove all mysql related folders from /var/lib/.
3. Reinstall MySQL.
4. Check permissions on the new /var/lib/mysql/ files & folders. If your backed up files don't match, fix them to match. (Mine was

   `chown -R mysql:mysql location_to_backed_up_folder/`

   `chmod 750 location_to_backed_up_folder/mysql/ location_to_backed_up_folder/any_other_folders/`

   `chmod 640 location_to_backed_up_folder/all_other_files`
5. Stop mysql
6. Rename the backed up folder to "mysql"
7. Copy the backed up folder & files (preserving ownership & permissions) to /var/lib/

   `cp -aR location_of_backed_up_folder/ /var/lib/`
8. Restart mysql

Comment: saved my life ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can continue using Maria Db if you have a copy of  mysql-5.7 (in `/var/lib` while maria db got installed) to some temporary location.

Now, in your `/var/lib`, you will have a folder called mysql which is your current db (without your old dump).

Now, stop your mysql. Move the mysql folder in `/var/lib` to some location for safety purpose and move the mysql-5.7 folder to `/var/lib` and rename it as mysql. Set the same privileges as set for previous mysql folder.

Restart mysql service again. You will have the old dump now.

Comment: this does not work and causes the system failing to start