# Database lost ! MariaDB fresh installation

Tags: package-management, virtualbox, mysql, database, mariadb

I'm using an Ubuntu VM with VirtualBox (Ubuntu 16.04.1) and i'm learning MySQL and SQL commands in command line in general.

So i had a database created with the basics mysql installed on Ubuntu.
Then i installed MariaDB...
Now when i go with : mysql -u user -p
I have this message : ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'database'

I don't know where my first database is recorded but maybe i need to uninstall mariadb but i'm not sure of what happen with my situation.

Don't hesitate to give me tips or pieces of solutions. I might learn more with this than anything i was doing.

Comment: @Rinzwind. mysql and mariadb are both DBMS right ? i can install one at a time and create database but i loose them soon as i install another soft ?

Comment: AFAIK *uninstalling* (or even purging) the mysql *packages* should not have touched any existing databases. What does `ls /var/lib/mysql` say?

Comment: @steeldriver. I did not type any sort of sudo apt-get remove mysql before installing mariadb so... In /var/liv/mysql i have the mysql database, the one i just create with maria and i deduce with the same color pattern one called performance_schema but no trace of the ancient one. (some other files also:ib_logfile0 ib_logfile1 etc...)

Comment: Well, i will try the method proposed on other posts :
one here : https://askubuntu.com/questions/941756/accidentally-installed-mariadb-over-mysql-how-do-i-recover-my-mysql-databases?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

By default the databases are stored in /var/lib/mysql

Before removing the package from mariadb look in that directory, once done show us that appears.

Any doubt we will be resolving to solve it.