# Cannot access to Mysql database when upgrading to MariaDb

Tags: 16.04, server, permissions, apache2, mysql

I was using Mysql server on Ubuntu 16.04 and then I installed MariaDb. Now I can't access anymore my database using phpMyadmin with my old account. Does someone have any idea how to do it without losing my data?
I searched on the internet and I found this: [Accidentally installed MariaDB over Mysql. How do I recover my Mysql databases?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/941756/accidentally-installed-mariadb-over-mysql-how-do-i-recover-my-mysql-databases)
but it doesn't work. It gives me this error:

```
1018 - Can't read dir of '.' (errno: 13 "Permission denied")
```

and I still can't restore my old databases.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Question: mysql was still running when you installed mariadb? You will need to restore the dump you made from mysql databases. Are you using SElinux? https://linux.die.net/man/8/semanage  needs to be used to restore permissions if that is the case. Something like `semanage fcontext -a -t mysqld_db_t “/var/lib/mysql(/.*)?”
restorecon -Rv /var/lib/mysql`

Comment: thank you for your answer.
yes mysql was running, no I'm not using SElinux I used just chmod command to change permissions

Comment: "mysql was running" that is going to be bad; you will need to restore a backup. You can't have mariadb and mysql at the same time.... chmod or chown? You need to own the databases too ;) "Can't read dir of '.' " could be a setting in the conf file too.

Comment: yes I tried this http://www.queryadmin.com/1501/error-1018-hy000-cant-read-dir-errno-13-mysql/ also with chown and chmod, but still not working. phpmyadmin still gives the error after I tried the two solutions from the websites I shared before. I removed mariadb and also mysql now and I tried to install mysql-server again but it gives this error:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.7 but it is not going to be installed